# Solving an equation with 2 square terms

Tags: quadratics

Consider this equation;

$$ 3x^2 + 2dx - d^2 = 0 $$

Now I need to find the value of x.I've consider using the quadratic formula but I've got 2 squared terms. I've also tried forming the equation to get x squared on one side, but than I'm not sure what to next. Any help on this?

Thank you!

Comment: where is the equation?

Comment: This is not an equation.  What is it equal to?  If it is equal to $0$, you can just apply the quadratic formula.  The linear term is $2d$ and the constant is $-d^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the question is to solve $3x^2+2dx-d^2=0$ for $x$ you can just apply the quadratic formula, getting
$$x=\frac {-2d \pm \sqrt{4d^2-4 \cdot 3 \cdot (-d^2)}}{2 \cdot 3}=\frac {-2d\pm 4d}6=\frac d3,-d$$

Comment: Wait I can apply the quadratic formula here, but how? I have 2 square terms and no c term,the term that isnt squared or has an x component?

Comment: Yes.  The $c$ term of your expression is $(-d^2)$.  In general, when you are solving for $x$  it is all the stuff that does not have a factor of $x$.  If you are solving for $x$, $d$ is a constant which specifies the problem.

Comment: Oh okay so we can look at that way. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

$3x^2 + 2dx - d^2=3(x+d)(x-d/3)$ so $x=-d$ or $x=d/3$